# No "efi" option during manual disk partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, live-usb

I was trying to install kubuntu 15.10 with the official image(downloaded from kubuntu.org) from live-usb, created with usb-creator-kde.

The notebook had already installed windows 8 in uefi mode.

I identified 100mb /dev/sda2 partition with fat as the bootloader partition, and was expecting to see something resembling this picture from tutorial
[image]

However, the "type" field of /dev/sda2 was fat32 and there was no option "efi" if I tried to change it, only "reserved bios partition", ext2, ext3, ext4, ntfs and so forth.

I also was worried by the fact that ubuntu have not recognized existing windows installation, usually it provides option of "installing alongside windows"

As I understand, this happened because I logged in with legacy live-usb kubuntu mode rather than uefi, however I don't see any other option during startup and if I try to manually add "uefi" option to the start command parameters I get kernel panic.

What is the proper way to make live-usb with ubuntu for uefi computer?

Comment: You have to select a new partition of around 100-500MB and click on `change`, in it you will see an option of `EFI partition`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. I guess this means that I won't be able to keep original windows efi bootloader, hopefully boot-restore will manage to do his job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with your question:

> What is the proper way to make Live USB with Ubuntu for UEFI computer ?

Create a working USB drive by using the **disks** tool from within Ubuntu.
Open it and select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right.
Choose the ISO file and the USB drive to write it to and start restoring.

Now to your screenshot:

So far everything seems to be just the way it should be.

Install Ubuntu to the already existing partition `sda6`.

But the **device** for boot loader installation – you have to **select `sda`**.
The boot loader will automatically be installed to EFI partition `sda2`.

Comment: Thanks for lengthy answer and  the tip about device for boot loader installation! However this screenshot isn't mine, it's from tutorial, in my screenshot instead of "efi" I see "fat32" and not able to change it to "efi", that was my original question :)

Comment: @trainset : Open GParted (included in the Ubuntu install media - mark sda2 - right-click - choose flags - check 'boot' and 'esp' ! :)

Comment: It actually doesn't matter what you choose to install grub to when booting in EFI mode; it *always* goes to the ESP.  That is, the choice of where to install grub is completely ignored in EFI mode.

Answer (score -2):

Fat32 is uses for Linux. NTFS is used for windows partitions. You can also install Linux alongsode Windows and use the windows boot manager if it will save any troublr. You need to delete the efi folder in your drive and reinstall once your done installing all operating systems. You shouldn't have to repartition. Also if you're having trouble with partitions, DOS command has a partitioning utility. You simply must use DOS strings and set the portion by KB integers from 0 to say 256000 in order. So your second partition might start at 45,128 for example but its size must match with the other partitions and if you,re not exact you may have to use a better formatting utility.

Comment: On an EFI-based computer, the ESP is FAT. The ESP holds *both* Linux *and* Windows boot loaders. Using the Windows boot manager rather than GRUB is likely to complicate things, not simplify them. It's unclear what you mean by "delet[ing] the efi folder," but the most likely interpretations would create new problems. DOS's `FDISK` would be useless on modern GPT disks, although there is a command-line tool (`DISKUTIL`, IIRC) available in Windows for this job. I wouldn't recommend using it for creating Linux partitions.

Comment: There should be a folder in the system files. You will need to find a tutorial for your boot manager. Delete it restart and run the installer again.