# boot repair disk not loading - boots into black screen

Tags: boot-repair, nomodeset

I am trying to fix a grub issue issue using the [boot repair disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) that I created with [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io). I do this by plugging in the bootable disk into the computer, booting into BIOS, and setting the USB drive as the primary boot device. I have successfully done this many times in the past with this disk.Since it seemed to not be working, I  formatted the USB and created another bootable Boot Repair Disk.

Upon booting from BIOS from the USB stick I am confronted with the primary grub loader for Boot Disk which gives the option to edit the launch settings for Boot Repair disk. Hitting enter simply yielded a black screen, so I rebooted and this time edited the launch options with `-nomodeset`, but it never reaches the GUI environment.(It started to load once but never made it fully into the GUI).

I also downloaded [Super Grub 2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) but could not get that working either as it seemed to get stuck in a boot loop. (there was only one launch option in the launch options which was 'DEFAULT', and when I select that the boot countdown recommences and it stays like that in a loop forever until I shut down or reboot)

I am running a 64 bit installation of Ubuntu 14.04 on a dual boot machine with Windows7 that boots primarily with Windows Loader. I then launch my Ubuntu from a Grub4Dos that is launched by the Windows loader.

Hardware setup is a GeForce GTX 970 graphics card, Intel i5-6500 processor, GIGABYTE Z170N-GAMING 5 MOtherboard running F4 BIOS, with 16 GIGS of DDR4 Ram

I am confused as to why this wont work. I have used this awwesome tool on many machines without fail. I desperately need this utility as it is an integral tool for fixing boot options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 970 is a quite new graphics adapter, which often has compatibility issues with the open source nouveau drivers. Boot from the USB drive - once the GRUB menu appears, press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add the parameter `nouveau.modeset=0` instead of `nomodeset`. Now you should be able to boot properly into the boot-repair-disk environment. The same method is valid for successfully booting other Linux based distributions and most of the Linux installation media.

Comment: something has gone wrong, and id like you to help me if you can. After reinstalling grub2, I am now unable to use Boot Disk Repair, this time though ti will load, but go into a menu first that has 'default', '64 but', '64bit failsafe', and 'Boot Disk Repair' I have tried each entry with `nouveau.modeset=0` but it only starts to load in a shell with a whole plethora of commands running, then suddenly stops and will not boot. I can CTRL ALT DEL to get out of it, but it fails to load again.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid : As I know from your other question, you seem to have a mixed boot situation of systems installed in legacy BIOS and EFI based BIOS mode. Create the boot-repair-disk media with the disks tool -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/689423/no-efi-option-during-manual-disk-partitions/689429#689429. Boot into BIOS and select the entry with UEFI in front, in case there is none with UEFI, choose the normal one ... then add the parameter ... hopefully this may work for you. :)

Comment: yes, I usually did see the EUFI in front of the device name when going into BOOT manager, however this time it only shows the disk name and no second entry with EUFI in front of it. Booting from this entry (with no EUFI on label) boots into the BOot Disk Rpeiar menu option as described above

Comment: @KalamalkaKid : Unfortunately I don't know whether the efi boot files are included in the boot-repair-disk, because I always use the built-in tools (which do their job perfectly right) as described in my other answer. But as you say that it loads, I think it has more to do with the mixed installation mode and boot-repair-disk this time doesn't recognize the setup properly. :)

Comment: i got it working by setting UEFI only in the BIOS setup !THanks again for all your help

Answer (score 1):

I misread your post and had a walkthrough on fixing the USB volume. I'm sorry, this was a gross error on my part.

You can fix a boot volume all you want, but you'll never fix a PHYSICALLY BAD DISK.

From an ubuntu installer disk, run repair mode. It shouldn't take you to a GUI, you should be left at a prompt.

I *believe* this disk has fdisk and badblocks, which are the two programs you need to verify the disk you're attempting to repair.

From the root prompt run

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and provide us the output.

Also, if you can easily identify which drive you're attempting to repair run...

```
sudo badblocks /dev/[devicename]
```

Device name should look something like "sda" or "nvme0" or "hda".

Please provide that output as well.

Comment: the issue was not the disk as I tried on different disks. The above answer was correct for my situation. Thanks for trying.